# Como mudar a imagem exibida nas versões Desktop e Mobile de um website

Tags: css, css-hover, css-font-face, css-transições, css-animations

Eu precisava que na versão desktop de um website fosse exibida uma imagem e na versão mobile outra imagem.

Sendo que no desktop o contador ficaria em cima da imagem (como ele já fica) e no mobile mostraria outra imagem, e o contador embaixo.

A página é essa aqui:

> https://www.boutiqueinfantil.com.br/black-friday

Não tenho muita experiência em programação.

[image: Página do website na versão desktop]

[image: Página do website na versão mobile]

Comment: Você está utilizando bootstrap? se estiver basta usar a classe `hidden-xs`

Comment: Cara vc tem a possibilidade de editar essa imagem?Pois pelo que vi ela tem um longo pedaço a direita epenas com um fundo preto, tipo o símbolo está de um lado e tem um pedação vazio todo preto do outro... não tem necessidade disso. Vc tem acesso a essa imagem para edita-la ou troca-la caso precise?

Comment: Sim  Hugo ai como boto pra ela se alinhar

Answer (score 2):

No seu arquivo CSS você pode utilizar Media Query, que possibilita alterar o comportamento do CSS para resoluções diferentes.

Nesse caso o ideal seria ter duas imagens diferentes no seu html.
Sendo que a imagem para desktop fique visível por padrão, e a para mobile oculta

Através do exemplo abaixo ((max-width: 700px)) caso a resolução da tela seja no máximo 700px, você pode colocar código css personalizado que funcionará somente nesse situação.

Exemplo:

```
/** Para mostrar somente no celular*/
@media (max-width: 700px) 
{
  .imagem_mobile
   {
       display: block;
   }
   .imagem_desktop{
       display: none;
   }
}
```